# pandas rounding, is this a bug?

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

is this a bug? When I am rounding at 4 decimal, it actually returns different result.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('precision', 10)

pd.DataFrame([[1.446450001],[1.44645]]).round(4)
```

result

```
    0
0   1.4465
1   1.4464
```

Comment: Not a bug.  1.44645 probably gets stored as binary as something that rounds down.

Comment: @piRSquared how could I fix this?

Comment: @piRSquared No, this is wrong. It's about rounding strategies

Comment: @MaxNoe Ahh! Thanks, I'm reading up this now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug - rather, it's an undocumented quirk.

DataFrame.round uses numpy.around under the hood, which:

> For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, Numpy rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.around.html

More readings @ Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: Patches to add a note about this in the pandas `round` docstring are very welcome :-) (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)

Answer (score 2):

There are two different rounding strategies

- The first rounds like you may have learned it in school, values at the exact half of an interval (ending with `5`) are rounded upwards
- The second rounds to the next *even* number

The first strategy has the side effect, that your in the mean have a positive bias, because the center is always tuned higher. This is fixed by the second strategy with the arbitrary decision to round to the next even value.

Pandas chose to use `numpy.around` which implements the second strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do normal rounding in pandas or python with the following function:

```
import numpy

def round_normal(n, decimals):
    # multiply the decimal by 10 to the number of decimals you want to round to
    multiplicand = 10 ** decimals

    # add 0.5 so that taking the floor will get you the right number when you 
    # divide by the multiplicand

    # e.g. 3.0449 to 2.d.p -> 304.49 + 0.5 = 304.59 -> floor(304.59) / 100 = 3.04
    # e.g. 3.045 to 2.d.p -> 304.5 + 0.5 = 305 -> floor(305) / 100 = 3.05
    rounded_n = numpy.floor(n * multiplicand + 0.5) / multiplicand
    return rounded_n
```